# Error in as.vector(x) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Tags: r, bash, genomicranges

I am trying to run an R script on the command line of bash (I am using CentOS 8) with the command:
`cat 1_myScript.R | R --slave --args $SAMPLE"_x" $SAMPLE"_y"`

where $SAMPLE is an argument that I have specified in the R script as follows

`> args<-commandArgs()`

`> aaa<-args[4]`

This syntax always worked for all of my scripts, but now it gives me the following error:

> Error in as.vector(x) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

> Calls: setdiff -> setdiff.default ->  -> as.vector

> Execution halted

the strange thing is that if I try to run this script in the R console

`>source("1_myScript.R")`

it proceeds with no errors. I have looked up and it appears to be a feature linked to the library "GenomicRanges", which I used in the script.
Here is the body of my script (note that I don't know the exact line where it fails):

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library(rtracklayer)
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
#args <- commandArgs()
#aaa<-args[4]
aaa<-gsub("_T.finalSorted.bam_CNVs","",args[1])
targDir<-"/srv/ngsdata/dalteriog/SV_analysis/example/WGS_NB_novogene/CNVDir/"
dataTable <-fread((paste0(targDir,args[2]), header=TRUE)
ratio<-data.frame(dataTable)

dataTable <-fread(paste0(targDir,args[1]), header=FALSE)
cnvs<- data.frame(dataTable)

ratio$Ratio[which(ratio$Ratio==-1)]=NA

cnvs.bed=GRanges(cnvs[,1],IRanges(cnvs[,2],cnvs[,3])) # primo ogetto del GRange obj --> chr; secondo --> range
ratio.bed=GRanges(ratio$Chromosome,IRanges(ratio$Start,ratio$Start),score=ratio$Ratio) # score è un metadata

overlaps <- subsetByOverlaps(ratio.bed,cnvs.bed) # regioni overlappanti i due df
normals <- setdiff(ratio.bed,cnvs.bed) # regioni diverse
normals <- subsetByOverlaps(ratio.bed,normals) # la stessa cosa, ma con lo score associato

#mu <- mean(score(normals),na.rm=TRUE)
#sigma<- sd(score(normals),na.rm=TRUE)

#hist(score(normals),n=500,xlim=c(0,2))
#hist(log(score(normals)),n=500,xlim=c(-1,1))

#shapiro.test(score(normals)[which(!is.na(score(normals)))][5001:10000])
#qqnorm (score(normals)[which(!is.na(score(normals)))],ylim=(c(0,10)))
#qqline(score(normals)[which(!is.na(score(normals)))], col = 2)

#shapiro.test(log(score(normals))[which(!is.na(score(normals)))][5001:10000])
#qqnorm (log(score(normals))[which(!is.na(score(normals)))],ylim=(c(-6,10)))
#qqline(log(score(normals))[which(!is.na(score(normals)))], col = 2)

numberOfCol=length(cnvs)

for (i in c(1:length(cnvs[,1]))) {
  values <- score(subsetByOverlaps(ratio.bed,cnvs.bed[i])) #score bayesiano della iesima CNV che overlappa con il file ratio 
  #wilcox.test(values,mu=mu)
  W <- function(values,normals){resultw <- try(wilcox.test(values,score(normals)), silent = TRUE)
    if(class(resultw)=="try-error") return(list("statistic"=NA,"parameter"=NA,"p.value"=NA,"null.value"=NA,"alternative"=NA,"method"=NA,"data.name"=NA)) else resultw}
  KS <- function(values,normals){resultks <- try(ks.test(values,score(normals)), silent = TRUE)
    if(class(resultks)=="try-error") return(list("statistic"=NA,"p.value"=NA,"alternative"=NA,"method"=NA,"data.name"=NA)) else resultks}
  #resultks <- try(KS <- ks.test(values,score(normals)), silent = TRUE)
  # if(class(resultks)=="try-error") NA) else resultks
  cnvs[i,numberOfCol+1]=W(values,normals)$p.value
  cnvs[i,numberOfCol+2]=KS(values,normals)$p.value
  }

if (numberOfCol==5) {
  names(cnvs)=c("chr","start","end","copy number","status","WilcoxonRankSumTestPvalue","KolmogorovSmirnovPvalue")  
}
if (numberOfCol==7) {
  names(cnvs)=c("chr","start","end","copy number","status","genotype","uncertainty","WilcoxonRankSumTestPvalue","KolmogorovSmirnovPvalue")  
}
if (numberOfCol==9) {
  names(cnvs)=c("chr","start","end","copy number","status","genotype","uncertainty","somatic/germline","precentageOfGermline","WilcoxonRankSumTestPvalue","KolmogorovSmirnovPvalue")  
}

cnvs$Wfdr <- p.adjust(cnvs$WilcoxonRankSumTestPvalue, method="BH",n=nrow(cnvs))
cnvs$KSfdr <- p.adjust(cnvs$KolmogorovSmirnovPvalue, method="BH",n=nrow(cnvs))
cnvs<-subset(cnvs, Wfdr <= 0.05 & KSfdr <= 0.05)



samp<-gsub("_T.finalSorted.bam_CNVs","",aaa)
cnvs<-add_column(cnvs, Sample=samp, .before=1)
write.table(cnvs, file=paste(targDir,aaa,"CNV.p.filtered.txt",sep=""),sep="\t",quote=F,row.names=F)
```

Comment: It would help if we had at least the portion of your script that is failing, and what those two arguments mean.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I loaded the whole script by editing this post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that the problem stands at the line 22:

```
normals <- setdiff(ratio.bed,cnvs.bed)
```

in this case, we want to find differences between two granges objects, but the function that does this operation is `setdiff` of GenomicRanges, that is masked by the package base. The solution to the answer is to edit such line in this way:

```
normals <- GenomicRanges::setdiff(ratio.bed,cnvs.bed)
```

Thank you again for your effort!